# Capitalize first and third word of a pandas dataframe value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jira

I have a dataframe column that has the following values:

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME      
---------------------
ROBERT             
HENRY              
THOMSON AND THOMSON
```

The dataframe would be added to a dictionary to create a new issue in JIRA.

```
new_issue = {new_issue[employee_name] = {'value':df_new_positives.EMPLOYEE_NAME.iloc[i].title()}
```

Calling the title() function is converting first letter in each word to start with a capital letter. In this case, I would like to convert the names to Robert, Henry,  Thomson and Thomson while making update to JIRA.

**Expected names in JIRA:**
Robert
Henry
Thomson and Thomson

Please advise how to approach this change.

Comment: You may be able to do this more obviously with a normal `dict` if you only have a few (under 1000) names to convert! This would also more easily permit special logic (like special-casing a few names which have two capital letters like a Foo McBar)

Comment: Please post your exact expected output.

Comment: You may want to look into a regex for the nth word, such as this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351071/match-the-nth-word-in-a-line . However, as soon as your data changes, you'll need to update your code.  Therefore, I would also recommend @ti7's approach to instead process the data differently.  Perhaps split the words into separate columns.

Comment: Thank you @ti7. We have only 3 names - Robert, Henry and Thomson and Thomson for that column.